# input required depending on button of form

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

To enter data into my database I created this form. The user can enter data add by clicking the add button the information is entered into the database. I am using `required` to force the user to enter text.

Now I added the edit and delete button. Therefore the user shall select a record with the radio buttons provided. But with the `required` in the input elements it is only possible to do edit or delete if text is entered.

Is it somehow possible to assign the required to a certain button?

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td> 
      <input type="radio" name="aName" />
    </td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>record</td>
    </tr>
     <td> 
      <input type="radio" name="aName" />
    </td>
      <td>another</td>
      <td>record</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    <td>  
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter" required >
      </td>
      <td>
  <input type="text" placeholder="something" required>
        </td>
      </tr>



  </table>
    <input type="submit" value="add" formaction="form1.php" formmethod="post"/>

  <input type="submit" value="delete" formaction="form2.php" formmethod="post"/>

  <input type="submit" value="edit" formaction="form3.php" formmethod="post"/>
</form>
```

Comment: become more clear , what do you mean assign to a button?

Comment: If you run my snippet: When you press the add button without entering data it wont submit. That's because of the required in the input and that's what I want. But for deleting and editing, the required shall not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do this, is without using 'required', but  reproducing this html5 effect using event handlers, focus() and alert(). 
event.preventDefault() prevents the form to submit.
Check it:

```html
<form method="POST">
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td> 
      <input type="radio" name="aName" />
    </td>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>record</td>
    </tr>
     <td> 
      <input type="radio" name="aName" />
    </td>
      <td>another</td>
      <td>record</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    <td>  
  <input id="enter"  type="text" placeholder="enter"  >
      </td>
      <td>
  <input id="something" type="text" placeholder="something" >
        </td>
      </tr>

  </table>
    <input id="add" formaction="form1.php" formmethod="post"
 onclick="
 if(document.getElementById('enter').value===''){
 event.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById('enter').focus();
 alert('Please,fill out this field');    
 } else if(document.getElementById('something').value===''){
 event.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById('something').focus();
 alert('Please,fill out this field');    
 }"
 type="submit" value="add"/>
  <input id="delete"  type="submit" formaction="form2.php" formmethod="post value="delete"/>
  <input  id="edit"  type="submit" formaction="form3.php" formmethod="post value="edit"/>
</form>
```